# Calculating the amount of energy used for a charging session

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm feeding the current (`I` in `Ampere`) and voltage (`U` in `Volt`) of a wallbox every 10 seconds into a prometheus instance. The wallbox naturally reports higher current when it is plugged into an electric vehicle and a lower current when its not (some baseline current still persists of course for the wallbox' connectivity functionality).

Now I'm quite new to Prometheus and PromQL and was wondering how I'd go on and actually get aggregated data out from these single points in time, namely I want to get Watt Hours and aggregate further on those.

IIRC electrical work is calculated by `W = U x I x t`, so my idea was to somehow sum up the individual values up until a total value for an hour, like so:

```
// somehow get t(0), the first timestamp where values have been reported
// now for each data point we expect that U and I have been constant up until
// this point for simplicity
W(1) = U(1) x I(1) x (t(1) - t(0))
W(2) = U(2) x I(2) x (t(2) - t(1))
W(3) = U(3) x I(3) x (t(3) - t(2))
...
// one hour is comprised of 360 individual values (6 values per minute, 60 minutes per hour)
W(1..360) = W(1) + W(2) + ... W(360)
```

I guess I need some integral function for that, but I'm unsure if I'm doing the right thing:

```
sum_over_time(current[10s]) * sum_over_time(voltage[10s])
```

This gives me basically the same value like `current * voltage`, so a single electrical work value, but I have no idea how I'd aggregate this further properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should return energy consumption during last hour if `current` and `voltage` metrics are collected every 10 seconds:

```
sum_over_time(
  (last_over_time(current[20s]) * last_over_time(voltage[20s]))[1h:10s]
) * 10
```

The `10` multiplier is needed in order to calculate the consumed energy per each 10 second interval.

This promql query uses [subquery feature](https://prometheus.io/blog/2019/01/28/subquery-support/).

Update:
The query returns the energy in [Joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule), not `kWh`. The resulting value must be divided by `(3600*1000)` in order to convert the consumed energy to `kWh`:

```
sum_over_time(
  (last_over_time(current[20s]) * last_over_time(voltage[20s]))[1h:10s]
) * 10 / (3600*1000)
```

Comment: So, let me read that for my own understanding - we take the last value within 20s of timespan from either series so that there is guaranteed to be one value in it, multiply both values together and then sum over all via a subquery with a range of one 1h and a resolution of 10s, correct? What does the multiply-by 10 on the final sum do?

Comment: Ok, something is off with this, see https://puu.sh/IIB8r/b0fa583fca.png as example, on several days this calculates the energy consumption per hour to be more than 100 kWh, whereas the EV can only be loaded with as much as 11 kW per hour with this wallbox. Did I got something with the timespan / interval wrong?

Comment: The final multplly-by 10 calculates the energy consumed per each each 10 second interval. Note that the query returns the enery in [Joules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule), not kWh. You need to divide the result by `(3600*1000)` in order to convert Joule to kWh.